# Turn AutoCompleteTextView into a SearchView in ActionBar instead

Tags: android, google-places-api, autocompletetextview, searchview

I have a **AutoCompleteTextView** which gives user auto-completion search result from **Google Places API**. Once I was done I discovered **SearchView** and how it can be placed in the **ActionBar**. I checked out the SearchView example provided by google and added it to my application as a starting point (it lists the installed applications) but I don´t know how to proceed from here. I want to have the same functionality as AutoCompleteTextView but use the SearchView instead.
Any suggestion? 
The whole  class is provided below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.SearchableInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 * 
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class PlacesListSearchActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    private static final String TAG = "PlacesListActivity";

    private ResultReceiver mReceiver;

    private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener sharedPreferencesListener;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    public AutoCompleteTextView textView;

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private TextView mStatusView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.places_search);
        mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);


        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list);
        textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        textView.setHint("type store name");
        textView.setAdapter(adapter);
        textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (count%3 == 1) {
                adapter.clear();
                    GetPlaces task = new GetPlaces();
                    //now pass the argument in the textview to the task
                    task.execute(textView.getText().toString());
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchview_in_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        setupSearchView(searchItem);

        return true;
    }

    private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {

        if (isAlwaysExpanded()) {
            mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        } else {
            searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                    | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
        }

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        if (searchManager != null) {
            List<SearchableInfo> searchables = searchManager.getSearchablesInGlobalSearch();

            // Try to use the "applications" global search provider
            SearchableInfo info = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
            for (SearchableInfo inf : searchables) {
                if (inf.getSuggestAuthority() != null
                        && inf.getSuggestAuthority().startsWith("applications")) {
                    info = inf;
                }
            }
            mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
        }

        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        mStatusView.setText("Query = " + newText);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        mStatusView.setText("Query = " + query + " : submitted");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onClose() {
        mStatusView.setText("Closed!");
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() {
        return false;
    }

    class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
        @Override
        // three dots is java for an array of strings
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args)
        {
            Log.d("PlacesListActivity", "doInBackground");
            ArrayList<String> predictionsArr = new ArrayList<String>();
            try
            {
                URL googlePlaces = new URL(
                        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(args[0], "UTF-8") +
//                      "&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=" + SEARCHES FOR GEO CODES
                        "&types=establishment&language=en&sensor=true&key=" +
                        getResources().getString(R.string.googleAPIKey));

                Log.d("PlacesListActivity", googlePlaces.toString());

                URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        tc.getInputStream()));

                String line;
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                //take Google's legible JSON and turn it into one big string.
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                //turn that string into a JSON object
                JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); 
                //now get the JSON array that's inside that object            
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(predictions.getString("predictions"));

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    //add each entry to our array
                    predictionsArr.add(jo.getString("description"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
            Log.e("PlacesListActivity", "GetPlaces : doInBackground", e);
            } catch (JSONException e)
            {
            Log.e("PlacesListActivity", "GetPlaces : doInBackground", e);
            }

            return predictionsArr;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){
            Log.d("PlacesListActivity", "onPostExecute : " + result.size());
            //update the adapter
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_list);
            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            //attach the adapter to textview
            textView.setAdapter(adapter);

            for (String string : result) {
                Log.d("PlacesListActivity", "onPostExecute : result = " + string);
                adapter.add(string);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            Log.d("PlacesListActivity", "onPostExecute : autoCompleteAdapter" + adapter.getCount());
        }

    }

}
```

**After updating the code suggested by saxman, I can see that the query method in the provider is never called:**

My manifest file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rathinavelu.rea"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".PlacesListActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".PlacesListSearchActivity" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".TestMapActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SettingsPreferencesActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.rathinavelu.util.ConnectionChecker" >
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <service
            android:name=".places.PlacesRESTService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SYNC" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name=".places.PlacesSuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="com.rathinavelu.rea.places.search_suggestion_provider"
            android:syncable="false" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I use the same authority in the manifest, content provider and manifest file. I see the searchView in the menu and I have not modified the query method so It should just return the one line cursor. but the query method is never called. please help.
Another issue I just spotted is that the searchView does not show the specified search_hint!

**Providing more code**
**PlacesListSearchActivity.java**

```
public class PlacesListSearchActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String TAG = "PlacesListSearchActivity";

        private ResultReceiver mReceiver;

        private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener sharedPreferencesListener;
        private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        public AutoCompleteTextView textView;

        private SearchView mSearchView;
        private TextView mStatusView;

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
                setContentView(R.layout.places_search);
                mStatusView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);


                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list);
                textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
                adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                textView.setHint("type store name");
                textView.setAdapter(adapter);
                textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (count%3 == 1) {
                                adapter.clear();
                                        GetPlaces task = new GetPlaces();
                                        //now pass the argument in the textview to the task
                                        task.execute(textView.getText().toString());
                        }
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }

                });
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        // Inflate the options menu from XML
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.places_list_search_options_menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        // Tells your app's SearchView to use this activity's searchable configuration
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

//        setupSearchView(searchItem);

        return true;
    }
```

**places_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#dddddd">

<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**places_list_search_options_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.rathinavelu.rea.places.search_suggestion_provider">
</searchable>
```

**PlacesSuggestionProvider.java**

```
public class PlacesSuggestionProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "PlacesSuggestionProvider";

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.rathinavelu.rea.places.search_suggestion_provider";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/search");

    // UriMatcher constant for search suggestions
    private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 1;

    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

    private static final String[] SEARCH_SUGGEST_COLUMNS = {
            BaseColumns._ID,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID
    };

    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
                return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues arg1) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String sortOrder) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "query = " + uri);

        // Use the UriMatcher to see what kind of query we have
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Search suggestions requested.");
                MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(SEARCH_SUGGEST_COLUMNS, 1);
                cursor.addRow(new String[] {
                        "1", "Search Result", "Search Result Description", "content_id"
                });
                return cursor;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, just wondering, is there any advantage for using SearchView over AutoCompleteTextView for search functionality in action bar?

Comment: Terrific link for future vsitors; http://www.drzon.net/how-to-create-a-clearable-autocomplete-dropdown-with-autocompletetextview/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To get Places Autocomplete API results in a SearchView, you'll first need a ContentProvider for the API.

```
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class PlacesSuggestionProvider extends ContentProvider {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.google.places.search_suggestion_provider";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/search");

    // UriMatcher constant for search suggestions
    private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 1;

    private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;

    private static final String[] SEARCH_SUGGEST_COLUMNS = {
            BaseColumns._ID,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2,
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID
    };

    static {
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
        uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
                return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues arg1) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String sortOrder) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "query = " + uri);

        // Use the UriMatcher to see what kind of query we have
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Search suggestions requested.");
                MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(SEARCH_SUGGEST_COLUMNS, 1);
                cursor.addRow(new String[] {
                        "1", "Search Result", "Search Result Description", "content_id"
                });
                return cursor;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then add your Places Autocomplete API client code into the *query* method on the content provider.  You extract the user input as follows:

```
String query = uri.getLastPathSegment().toLowerCase();
```

Add the PlacesSuggestionProvider to your AndroidManifest, and make sure your activity has a searchable configuration.

```
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity android:name=".PlacesSearchViewActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="com.example.google.places.PlacesSuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.google.places.search_suggestion_provider"
            android:syncable="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And make sure your searchable configuration (res/xml/searchable.xml) has a search suggest authority.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.example.google.places.search_suggestion_provider">
</searchable>
```

The authority should be the same in AndroidManifest.xml, searchable.xml, and your content provider.

Create a options menu for your ActionBar that includes a SearchView (/res/menu/options_menu.xml).

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
          android:title="@string/menu_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Configure your Activity with a SearchView that's associated with your searchable configuration/

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    // Tells your app's SearchView to use this activity's searchable configuration
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default

    return true;
}
```

A few key docs are:

Adding Custom Suggestions:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

Creating a Content Provider:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

Using a Search Widget:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget

Comment: thanks for the reply. So the content provider will do the looking up at Google Places and return a cursor! But I still don´t know how the searchView is connected to it?

Comment: Added that code as well (last 2 code blocks). In onCreateOptionsMenu, you configure the SearchView to use the searchable configuration you defined for your activity.

Comment: It sounds like you might be missing the last part: associating your searchable config with the SearchView.  Please post your other files as well (searchable.xml, PlacesListSearchActivity, PlaceSuggestionProvider, and whatever you're using for the options menu).

Comment: I have added pretty much all the classes. searchable.xml & PlacesSuggestionProvider.java is pretty much your original code.

Comment: You need an <intent-filter> around the <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" /> in your manifest.

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get home ;) I can not believe I missed that and also I don´t understand why it did not complain!

Comment: A follow up question, how do I use the previously used onPostExecute into the query-method of the content provider?

Comment: Not sure I follow... But you don't need to use an AsyncTask in your ContentProvider query method; calls to query(...) are off the UI thread. For my implementation, I have a PlacesService class that has "autocomplete", "getDetails", and "search" methods. I call autocomplete from the search suggest ContentProvider, but can also call it from other widgets, such as the AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: Is it possible to add two search widget in the same action bar of an activity ?

Comment: How to find `searchView` onItemClickListner?

Comment: Thanks for the solution! A few comments: query method does run on the UI thread on API 19 at least. I am getting                                                                    `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` if ran just like that. Another issue I have spent 2 hours on: Replace the line                            `public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/search");` with                                  `public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY);` and all should be well

Comment: If going the way described above then the search query will not be available in `String query = uri.getLastPathSegment().toLowerCase();` but instea you may take it irectly from the query method arguments

Answer (score 1):

AutoCompleteTextView with google search Api

[image]

your xml

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/main_omnibox_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@null" 
    android:hint="Search"  
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"                                  
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
```

your java code

```
  this.inputBox = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.main_omnibox_input);
  inputBox.setAdapter(new SearchAutocompleteAdapter(SearchActivity.this, new SearchAutocompleteAdapter.OnSearchCommitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchCommit(String text) {
            inputBox.setText(text);
            inputBox.setSelection(text.length());
        }
    }));


    this.inputBox.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long j) {
            String charSequence = ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
            inputBox.setText(Html.fromHtml(BrowserUnit.urlWrapper(charSequence)), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            inputBox.setSelection(charSequence.length());
           // your code
           // updateAlbum(charSequence);
           // hideSoftInput(SearchActivity.this.inputBox);
        }
    });
```

SearchAutocompleteAdapter

```
public class SearchAutocompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

interface OnSearchCommitListener {
    void onSearchCommit(String text);
}

private final Context mContext;
private final OnSearchCommitListener commitListener;
private List<String> completions = new ArrayList<>();
static final String searchCompleteUrl = "https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=%s";

SearchAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, OnSearchCommitListener commitListener) {
    mContext = context;
    this.commitListener = commitListener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return completions.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return completions.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
    }
    TextView textview = convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    textview.setText(completions.get(position));
    Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.icon_goarrowsmall);
    final int size = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 32, mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    d.setBounds(0, 0, size, size);
    textview.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, d, null);

    textview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return false;
            }
            TextView t = (TextView) view;
            if (event.getX() > t.getWidth() - t.getCompoundPaddingRight()) {
                commitListener.onSearchCommit(getItem(position).toString());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    parent.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getX() > view.getWidth() - size * 2) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // Invoked on a worker thread
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                List<String> results = getCompletions(constraint.toString());
                filterResults.values = results;
                filterResults.count = results.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                completions = (List<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
}

private List<String> getCompletions(String text) {
    int total = 0;
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URLUtil.composeSearchUrl(text, searchCompleteUrl, "%s"));
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            while (total <= data.length) {
                int count = in.read(data, total, data.length - total);
                if (count == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                total += count;
            }
            if (total == data.length) {
                // overflow
                return new ArrayList<>();
            }
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    JSONArray jsonArray;
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    jsonArray = jsonArray.optJSONArray(1);
    if (jsonArray == null) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    final int MAX_RESULTS = 10;
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(Math.min(jsonArray.length(), MAX_RESULTS));
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length() && result.size() < MAX_RESULTS; i++) {
        String s = jsonArray.optString(i);
        if (s != null && !s.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(s);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}