# How to retrieve search suggestion from google places?

Tags: android, google-maps, search, android-searchmanager

I need to have the list of [suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) of `cities/streets/villages` while I am typing into the search bar. I found out that I have to implement [contentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491515/turn-autocompletetextview-into-a-searchview-in-actionbar-instead) and I make it. Now, for everything I type, I get the same result:

> "Search Result"

While [Google Places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551028/using-google-places-api) should return the correct list of the locations. Can someone help me? How can I make my search work as it works on googlemaps? (I mean the suggestions, the Geocoder stuff is done already). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the Code Snippet Which i have Used when i have similar problem.

here is my **PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter**.java File.

```
package com.inukshk.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

import com.inukshk.CreateInukshk.CreateInukshk;

public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements
        Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;

    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.

                    resultList = CreateInukshk.autocomplete(constraint
                            .toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                    FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

here is What you have to do inside **OnCreate()** of your activity.

```
autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editloc);
        autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item));
```

here are the static Strings i have used in app.

```
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";     
    private static final String API_KEY = "YOUR API KEY";
```

and Finally here is the Method that you will use in Adapter.

```
public static ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {

        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE
                    + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
            // sb.append("&components=country:uk");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "description"));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

i guess you have specified the list_item.xml as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

try it out. Hope it will helps you.